# cp file in many subdirectories with *

Tags: 12.04, bash

I want to copy a file "test.sh" in directories which have all a subdirectory 2_bas (ex. prod1/2_bas, prod2/2_bas, etc...)

I tried:

```
cp test */2_bas/
```

but I get the error message:

```
cp: omitting directory `prod1/2_bas'
cp: omitting directory `prod2/2_bas'
```

A solution would be:

```
for dir in *; do [ -d "$dir" ] && cp test.sh "$dir"/2_bas ; done
```

But why does the first strategy not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's how the `cp` command is designed to work; it accepts multiple sources but only one destination. So your expansion looks like:

```
cp test prod1/2_bas prod2/2_bas prod3/2_bas .... prodN/2_bas
```

and what you're telling `cp` is to essentially copy everything into prodN/2bas (the last directory in the expansion). This is certainly not what you want. The error message you see is because you're telling `cp` to copy directories, and by default it refuses to do so (unless you specify, for instance, `-r` for recursive copying. Don't do it, though; it will still not do what you want).

Have a look at `cp` man page, it states what the command does:

```
Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

Another solution:

```
find ./ -type -d exec cp test {} \;
```